# Read data from file in Android

Tags: android, file

I have to read some data stored in a file in the memory of the mobile phone. I can only read that when I print the result in the terminal, it only printouts me some lines. My file contains the following data:

[image]

I read this data with the following code:

```
 File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

            //Get the text file
            File file = new File(sdcard,"data.txt");

            //Read text from file
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    text.append(line);
                    text.append('\n');
                    System.out.println(line); //print the result on terminal
                }

                br.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                //You'll need to add proper error handling here
            }
```

But in the terminal it not print all line of the file. The result view in terminal is this: 
[image]

In this case it only displayed the last four data, while in other cases it displays everything. I can't understand why. Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: print text outside your while loop, may be it is a problem with your logcat.

Comment: @RajatMehra It not work, return only four elements

Comment: @MirkoMarasco see my answer it will work for you.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remove** `System.out.println()` from while loop and write your final text in `Log.d()` outside the loop

```
 File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    //Get the text file
    File file = new File(sdcard, "data.txt");

    //Read text from file
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
        Log.d("Activity","Final Text----->"+text);
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //You'll need to add proper error handling here
    }
```

Comment: @Mirko happy to help you..if the answer was helpful..upvote the answer.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
...
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
   text.append(line);
   text.append('\n');
}
Log.d("YOUR_TAG", line);
...
```